# Como usar o Redirect na minha aplicação React

Tags: javascript, react, aplicação-web, front-end, redux

Estou fazendo uma aplicação em react, estou usando o redux e o redux saga. Estou fazendo a proteção das rotas, porém quando eu faço o redirect não me leva para a pagina principla da minha alicação. Esse é o código do meu protectedRoute:

```
import React from "react";
import { Redirect, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function ProtectedRoute({ component: Component, ...restOfProps }) {
    const isAuthenticated = localStorage.getItem("isAuthenticated");
    console.log("Aqui")
    return (
        <Route
        {...restOfProps}
        render={(props) =>
            isAuthenticated ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect push to="/login" />
        }
        />
    );
}

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

E o meu arquivo de rotas está assim:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route, BrowserRouter, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Login from '../components/Login/index'
import Event from '../components/Event/index'
import Schedule from '../components/Schedule/index'
import ProtectedRoute from './protectedRoute';

const Routes = () => {
    return(
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
                <ProtectedRoute exact path="/" component={Event}/>
                <ProtectedRoute path="/schedule" component={Schedule} />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}

export default Routes;
```

No meu sagas eu faço a requisição para a minha API e e guardo o token no local storage:

```
import {all, call, fork, put, takeEvery, select} from "redux-saga/effects";
import axios from 'axios'
import {
    CLICK_BUTTON_LOGIN,
} from '../actions/actionTypes'
import { updateSuccess } from "../actions/login";

const verifyLoginInAPI = async(email,password) =>{
    return await axios.post("http://localhost:4000/user/login",{
        email: email,
        password: password
    })
    .then(response => response)
    .catch(error => error)
}

function* confirmDataLogin(){
    try{
        const email = yield select(state => state.login.email)
        const password = yield select(state => state.login.password)
        const result = yield call(() => verifyLoginInAPI(email, password))
        if(result.status === 200){
            localStorage.setItem("isAuthenticated",result.data.token)
        }
    }catch(e){
        yield call(() => console.error('ERRO: ', e))
    }
}

export function* confirmDataLoginSaga(){
    yield takeEvery(CLICK_BUTTON_LOGIN, confirmDataLogin)
}
```

Preciso de ajuda para: assim que o usuário fizer o login, ele ser redirecionado para a página principal.

Answer (score 0):

acho que seria mais facil utilizar isPrivate em cada componente e depois fazer a autenticação, a ideia é que um usuario so pode navegar para uma privada se a condição de login for true se não for sera rederecionado para tras, este é um exemplo de como eu costumo fazer essas validaçoes, tenta adaptar ao teu codigo

```
export default function RouteWrapper({
  component: Component,
  isPrivate,
  ...rest
}) {
  const { signed } = store.getState().auth;
  const { googleSigned } = store.getState().googleAuth;

  if (!googleSigned) {
    if (!signed && isPrivate) {
      return <Redirect to="/" />;
    }

    if (signed && !isPrivate) {
      return <Redirect to="/dashboard" />;
    }
  }

  if (googleSigned && !isPrivate) {
    return <Redirect to="/dashboard" />;
  }
```

```
export default function Routes() {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact component={SignIn} />

      <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} isPrivate />
      <Route path="/profile" component={Profile} isPrivate />
      <Route path="/pesquisarAulas" component={PesquisarAulas} isPrivate />
      <Route path="/escreverSumario" component={EscreverSumario} isPrivate />
    </Switch>
  );
}
```

```
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Content>{children}</Content>
    </Wrapper>
  );
}

AuthLayout.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.element.isRequired,
};
```

Comment: Por favor, adicione mais detalhes para expandir sua resposta, como um código que funcione ou citações de documentação.